# Long delay when pinging Windows 7 machine by name vs by ip

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, ping

This question regards machines accessing/pinging one another on my local network by name vs ip and delays associated with doing it by name. All machines are Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit.

Below is output from three scenarios:

1. Ping machine2 by name. The key issue is there is close to a **6 second delay** from hitting enter on the command line before results start being returned.

`C:\Users\machine1>ping machine2`

```
Pinging machine2 [fe80::95f5:38e3:fc8a:4a70%11] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::95f5:38e3:fc8a:4a70%11: time=1ms
Reply from fe80::95f5:38e3:fc8a:4a70%11: time=1ms
Reply from fe80::95f5:38e3:fc8a:4a70%11: time=1ms
Reply from fe80::95f5:38e3:fc8a:4a70%11: time=1ms

Ping statistics for fe80::95f5:38e3:fc8a:4a70%11:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms
```

2. Ping machine2 by ip. There is **no delay** from hitting enter to recieving results

`C:\Users\machine1>ping 192.168.1.101`

```
Pinging 192.168.1.101 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.101: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.101: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.101: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.101: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.101:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms
```

3. Force ping to use IPv4 and ping by machine name. Still same delay occurs.

`C:\Users\machine1>ping machine2 -4`

```
Pinging machine2 [192.168.1.101] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.101: bytes=32 time=58ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.101: bytes=32 time=86ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.101: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.101: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.101:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 86ms, Average = 41ms
```

The main time this becomes an issue is using programs where I just wanted to quickly type a machine name on the network to connect to, e.g. Remote Desktop, and having to wait 6 seconds each time, or alternatively look up its IP first, which isn't great when the IP changes. I'm not interested in static IP's either.

At this point I think this has to do more with machine name resolution than anything else, but don't know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had some problems getting the question formatted correctly especially with the command line and outputs. Should the output be a code block? It should all def. be monospaced. Any formatting wizards care to take a crack at it?

Answer (score 1):

The timeout will be in the DNS resolution.  It may be because you have more than one DNS server specified and one of them is not responding.

In a command prompt window type:

```
C:\> ipconfig /all | find "DNS Servers"
```

and note down the IP addresses of the DNS servers.

Then use the `nslookup` tool to probe them:

```
C:\> nslookup
Default Server: Blah
Address: 192.168.1.1

>
```

Then select each DNS server in turn:

```
> server 192.168.1.1
Default Server: [192.168.1.1]
Address: 192.168.1.1
```

and do a lookup using it:

```
> machine2
Server: [192.168.1.1]
Address: 192.168.1.1

Name: machine2.mydomain.com
Address: 192.168.1.101
```

Repeat that `server` and `machine2` commands for each IP address in your list.  One of them should fail with:

```
Request to [192.168.1.1] timed-out
```

Then it's just a case of finding out a) why that DNS server is not working, and b) if you should even be using it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses several different methods to resolve machine names:

- DNS
- NBNS, NetBIOS name service (used by all Windows version)
- LLMNR (introduced in Windows 7; only IPv6)
- mDNS (if Bonjour is installed; comes with iTunes and probably Safari)

It could be that your DNS server is not responding to the queries, or that the other machines have NBNS and/or LLMNR disabled or firewalled. (I don't know the exact order, but DNS always seems to be tried first.)

Install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and watch all packets related to name resolution. Set the display filter to *`dns or nbns or udp.port=5355`*.

Answer (score 1):

I actually ran into this problem recently on a linux system.

The cause turned out to be that once return packets start coming, certain versions of `ping` by default attempt to do a reverse DNS lookup of the IP address the response is coming from:

```
shadur@caleburn: ~/ > ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.136.113) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ea-in-f113.1e100.net (74.125.136.113): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=12.7 ms
64 bytes from ea-in-f113.1e100.net (74.125.136.113): icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=7.75 ms
64 bytes from ea-in-f113.1e100.net (74.125.136.113): icmp_seq=3 ttl=49 time=7.85 ms
```

If your setup doesn't have reverse DNS configured for the `1.168.192.in-addr.arpa` (or at least an entry for 192.168.1.1 in your `hosts` file, it's going to time out trying to reach a DNS server to complete the lookup, and it can't start printing the response packets until the lookup gets resolved (either by a correct DNS response in which case it prints the returned name, or by a timeout in which case it just prints the IP address).

Adding the name/IP address combo to your `hosts` file should fix the issue.

(**EDIT**: In windows the file you're looking for is at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` by default.)